# unresolved external symbol "std::atomic_fetch_add"

Tags: c++, atomic

Consider this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

void add(std::atomic<double> & a, double c)
{
    std::atomic_fetch_add(&a, c);
}

int main()
{
    std::atomic<double> a;

    a.store(0);
    std::cout << a.load() << std::endl;

    add(a, 5.0);
    std::cout << a.load() << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Compiling it will result in:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl std::atomic_fetch_add(struct std::atomic *,double)" (??$atomic_fetch_add@N@std@@YANPAU?$atomic@N@0@N@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl add(struct std::atomic &,double)" (?add@@YAXAAU?$atomic@N@std@@N@Z)

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_fetch_add), `atomic_fetch_add` is defined in `<atomic>`, so what is happening?

Comment: Who told you that `std::atomic` is specialized for `double`?

Comment: It is, but [none of the overloads take a double](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_fetch_add)

Comment: @Slava I didn't see anywhere that I can't use it for `double`!

Comment: @Jaber http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic - types explicitly listed for which `std::atomic` is fully or partially specialized, `double` is not in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic):

> The standard library provides specializations of the std::atomic template for the following types:

and `double` is not in the list. There is also note for non member functions:

> There are non-member function template equivalents for all member
>   functions of std::atomic. Those non-member functions may be
>   additionally overloaded for types that are not specializations of
>   std::atomic, but are able to guarantee atomicity. **The only such type
>   in the standard library is std::shared_ptr**.

So `double` is not supported.

Comment: Do you know any library which implemented atomic arithmetic for non-integral types?

Comment: @Jaber, no never needed such beast, I use mutex - premature optimization is root of all evil.

Comment: to clarify your answer: `double` is supported for basic atomic operations like (`load`, `store`, etc); but isn't supported for specialized operations (like arithmetic `+`, `-`, ...) as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048533/why-isnt-atomic-double-fully-implemented/30050429#30050429).